# How change INSTALLDIR while upgrade?

Tags: windows-installer, major-upgrade, installshield-2013

I'm changing my **`INSTALLDIR`** location in my installer. In my installer project,  previously I was installing at location "XYZ" and now I want to install at location "PQR". So I changed **`INSTALLDIR`** property in my installer. It's working fine for fresh installation but while upgrade scenario it's not changing INSTALLDIR. So how I can handle this issue for upgrade scenario?

Comment: What [type of upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx) are you talking about? Minor upgrade, major upgrade, ...?

Comment: Major upgrade..

Comment: When is RemoveExistingProducts scheduled? With some schedules, it makes a major upgrade about as picky as a minor upgrade.

Comment: RemoveExistingProducts is scheduled before InstallInitialize. But in the case of a minor upgrade as well, How I can change that INSTALLDIR?

Comment: With this configuration of RemoveExistingProducts the directory change should basically work for a major upgrade I believe (just tested with IS2018). Maybe you persisted INSTALLDIR in the registry and read it back yourself? In that case you would need to tweak it after retrieval to avoid it overriding your new folder. Also, moving files in a minor upgrade borders on the impossible I believe. I rarely use minor upgrade due to all the restrictions they have.

Comment: @AjitMedhekar, did you get a solution for this? I myself am facing a similar issue.